# divide duplicate values by the number of duplicates for that value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a VBA code or excel formula that will divide duplicate values by the number of duplicates for that value.  For example
A- 6
B- 8
C- 3
D- 4
F- 5
A- 8
A- 4

The code would add 6+8+4 and then divide by 3.  It would replace each current value for A with 6.

Comment: Ok, so what is the question here?

Comment: Clarification on the question:  It would not need to add the values together, it would just divide each A value by 3 since there are 3 duplicates

Comment: That's still not a question. Anyhow, you can do this in excel using COUNTIF and a simple formula.

Answer (score 0):

Meh...

Say column A contains your letters, Column B contains your numbers, and row 1 is a header row. Enter this formula in cell C2 and pull it down:

```
=B2/COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark as answer then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Averageif formula

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B)
```